# Keydown Events are not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am trying to work on a basic calculator for fun. I tried to attach a few events so the user van use ENTER to get the result and backspace to go back. However, the keyboard events are not working.

I also do not understand why the C appears in the screenbox when pressed to empty it.

What can be the issue??

I made a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9gvbd2nt/1/

```
const screen = document.getElementById('screen');
let screenValue = '';
const allowed = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '(', '=', '-', '/', '*', '+', ')', 'C'];

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((b) => {
    b.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let button = e.target.innerText;
        if (screenValue == '' && allowed.splice(11, 15).includes(button)) {
            console.log('Invalid Character: ' + button)
        }
        if (button === 'C') {
            screenValue = '';
            screen.value = screenValue;
        }
        if (button === '=') {
            evalTest(screen.value);
        } else {
            screenValue += button;
            screen.value = screenValue;
        }
        screen.focus();
    })
})

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === 13) {
        e.preventDefault;
        evalTest(screen.value);
    }
    if (e.key === 8) {
        e.preventDefault;
        screenValue = screenValue.slice(-1);
        screen.value = screenValue;
    }
})

function evalTest(value) {
    const regex = new RegExp('[0-9\/\*\)\(\+\-\=\%]*')
    if (value.match(regex)[0] == value) {
        screen.value = eval(value);
    } else {
        alert('Illegal Operation');
    }
}
```

Comment: But where is your attempt to attach keydown event? I see only click and even this event is not predefined. Predefined one is "onclick"

Comment: I edited it i didnt copy it also

Comment: And this  `allowed.splice(11, 15).includes(button)` is strange code. Splice change array itself, not making copy. What is the meaning of it?

Comment: The `C` is being input because you have 2 `if`s in a row with an `else` but they should be chained together with `if else` so it doesn't evaluate the last `else` when the first `if` is true. `if (button === 'C') { code } else if (button === '=') { code } else { code }`. Right now the first `if` is true so it's clearing `screenValue`, but then the second `if` is false so it's going to the `else` where it's adding `C` to `screenValue`.

Comment: Dmitri, the reason is because the characters '/', '*', '+', ')' should not be input when the screen is empty. I dont want to make a copy of the array why would I want to do that?

Comment: Thank you WOUNDEDStevenJones, I didnt realize that. That part works now

Comment: @Realm, ah, okay, if you do it conciously then no problems

Comment: @Realm are you going to mark an answer?

Comment: @berkobienb I marked it

Comment: @Realm Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `e.key` to `e.which` or `e.keyCode`.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault;
        evalTest(screen.value);
    }
    if (e.which === 8) {
        e.preventDefault;
        screenValue = screenValue.slice(-1);
        screen.value = screenValue;
    }
})
```

**Update:** the `which` and `keyCode` property are deprecated. You shouldn't use the ASCII value to check the `key` property, just the name of the key:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault;
    evalTest(screen.value);
  }
  if (e.key === "Backspace") {
    e.preventDefault;
    screenValue = screenValue.slice(-1);
    screen.value = screenValue;
  }
})
```

Here are a list of Key Values if you want to check for others in the future:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

Comment: But my visualCode says that which and keyCode are deprecated? It says key is what should be used now